# Adding automatically generated key in Firebase using Angular JS

Tags: angularjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm currently working with Angular 1.4.5 and Firebase 4.3.0 and have some questions need to ask.

I want to know that how can I add the key which is generated automatically by Firebase into the data of particular item.

For example, by following the tutorial, I've managed to store the user ID generated by Firebase using uid

my Firebase data structure:

[image: Click here to see my Firebase data structure]

And this is the code

```
myApp.factory('Authentication', ['$rootScope', '$location', '$firebaseObject','$firebaseAuth',function($rootScope, $location, $firebaseObject, $firebaseAuth){

var ref = firebase.database().ref();
var auth = $firebaseAuth();
var myObject;

auth.$onAuthStateChanged(function(authUser){
  if(authUser){
    var userRef = ref.child('users').child('accounts').child(authUser.uid);
    var userObj = $firebaseObject(userRef);
    $rootScope.currentUser = userObj;
  }else {
    $rootScope.currentUser = '';
  }
});

myObject = {
  login: function(user){
    auth.$signInWithEmailAndPassword(
      user.email,
      user.password
    ).then(function(user){
      $location.path('/home');
    }).catch(function(error){
      $rootScope.message = error.message;
    });//signInWithEmailAndPassword
  },//login

  logout: function(){
    return auth.$signOut();
  }, //logout

  requireAuth: function(){
    return auth.$requireSignIn();
  },//require Authentication

  register: function(user){
    auth.$createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
      user.email,
      user.password
    ).then(function(regUser){
      var regRef = ref.child('users').child('accounts').child(regUser.uid).set({
        date: firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP,
        regUser: regUser.uid,
        firstname: user.firstname,
        lastname: user.lastname,
        email: user.email
      }); //userinfo
      myObject.login(user);
    }).catch(function(error){
      $rootScope.message = error.message;
    });//createUserWithEmailAndPassword
  }//register
};//return

return myObject;}]);//factory
```

This is the code i use to add item into Firebase (function uploadItem and uploadItem1)

```
pageControllers.controller('UploadController',['$scope', '$firebaseAuth', '$firebaseArray',
function($scope, $firebaseAuth, $firebaseArray){

  var ref = firebase.database().ref();
  var auth = $firebaseAuth();

  auth.$onAuthStateChanged(function(authUser){
    if(authUser){
      var recipesRef = ref.child('users').child('accounts').child(authUser.uid).child('recipes');
      var recipesInfo = $firebaseArray(recipesRef);

      var recipes1Ref = ref.child('users').child('recipes');
      var recipes1Info = $firebaseArray(recipes1Ref);

      var favoritesRef = ref.child('users').child('accounts').child(authUser.uid).child('favorites');
      var favoritesInfo = $firebaseArray(favoritesRef);

      $scope.recipes = recipesInfo;
      $scope.favorites = favoritesInfo;

      $scope.uploadItem = function(){
        recipesInfo.$add({
          name: $scope.foodname,
          category: $scope.foodcategory,
          image: $scope.foodimage,
          howtocook:$scope.foodhowtocook,
          video:$scope.foodvideo,
          date: firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP
        }).then(function(){
          $scope.foodname = ' ';
          $scope.category = ' ';
          $scope.foodimage = ' ';
          $scope.foodhowtocook = ' ';
          $scope.foodvideo = ' ';
          $scope.message = 'Your recipes has been uploaded successfully!!';
        });//promise
      }//uploadItem

      $scope.uploadItem1 = function(){
        recipes1Info.$add({
          name: $scope.foodname,
          category: $scope.foodcategory,
          image: $scope.foodimage,
          howtocook:$scope.foodhowtocook,
          video:$scope.foodvideo,
          date: firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP
        }).then(function(){
          $scope.foodname = ' ';
          $scope.category = ' ';
          $scope.foodimage = ' ';
          $scope.foodhowtocook = ' ';
          $scope.foodvideo = ' ';
          $scope.message = 'Your recipes has been uploaded successfully!!';
        });//promise
      }//uploadItem

      $scope.addFavorite = function(name){
        favoritesInfo.$add({
          name: name,
          // name: $scope.itemName,
          // index: $scope.itemIndex,
          date: firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP
        }).then(function(){
          $scope.message = 'Success!';
          $('#Popup').modal();
          console.log(name);
        });//promise
      }//uploadItem

      $scope.deleteFavorite = function(key){
        favoritesInfo.$remove(key);
      } //deleteFavorite

      $scope.deleteRecipe = function(key){
        recipesInfo.$remove(key);
      } //deleteFavorite

    }//authUser
  });//onAuthStateChanged}]);//myAll.controller
```

I want to add the key of each item into its data like putting the uid into the users data but i don't know how.

Answer (score 0):

what i understand from your question is that you want to store the auto generated key from the firebase into the items that you push like below,
[image]

If you want something like this, it can be done in two ways

1 ) Pure firebase Coding

```
$scope.uploadItem1 = function(){
  var receipeInfoKey=recipes1Ref.push().key
  or var receipeInfoKey=ref.child('users').child('recipes').push().key;
  var receipeInfoObj={}
   receipeInfoObj= {
      name: $scope.foodname,
      category: $scope.foodcategory,
      image: $scope.foodimage,
      howtocook:$scope.foodhowtocook,
      video:$scope.foodvideo,
      date: firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP,
      receipeKey:receipeInfoKey
    }
 recipes1Ref .child(receipeInfoKey).set(receipeInfoObj)
 or 
 ref.child('users').child('recipes').child(receipeInfoKey).set(receipeInfoObj)
 .then(function(){
      $scope.foodname = ' ';
      $scope.category = ' ';
      $scope.foodimage = ' ';
      $scope.foodhowtocook = ' ';
      $scope.foodvideo = ' ';
      $scope.message = 'Your recipes has been uploaded successfully!!';
    });//promise
  }//uploadItem
```

2 ) Angular fire

// This method will be like updating the recipes1Info object after the successful push

```
$scope.uploadItem1 = function(){
    recipes1Info.$add({
      name: $scope.foodname,
      category: $scope.foodcategory,
      image: $scope.foodimage,
      howtocook:$scope.foodhowtocook,
      video:$scope.foodvideo,
      date: firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP
    }).then(function(recipes1Ref){
      var receipePushedObj= recipes1Info.$getRecord(recipes1Ref.key); 
       // recipes1Ref.key this is the auto generated key after the successful push

      if(receipePushedObj!=null){
         receipePushedObj.receipeKey=recipes1Ref.key;
         recipes1Info.$save(receipePushedObj);
      }
      $scope.foodname = ' ';
      $scope.category = ' ';
      $scope.foodimage = ' ';
      $scope.foodhowtocook = ' ';
      $scope.foodvideo = ' ';
      $scope.message = 'Your recipes has been uploaded successfully!!';
    });//promise
```

here is the working sample of the first method I proposed.[Js Fiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/0y4xomeq/2/)